# How to find biggest value in the 4 dimensional dicitonary in python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with 16 as a first key, 32 as second and 64 as third, here is a snippet:

```
perf = {
16: 
    {
        0.3: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}},
        0.5: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}},
        0.7: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}
        }
    }
}
```

And those zeros will by filled with numbers and when it is done I want to know which combination has the biggest val_accuracy. In return I want to have the keys like `(16, 0.7, 0.01)`. And if it is possible I would like to have multiindex dataframe instead of this dictionary.

Comment: "if it is possible I would like to have multiindex dataframe instead of this dictionary." Well, what happened when you tried to read the documentation, or put something like "multi index dataframe from nested dictionary" into a search engine? What happened when you tried to write your own code to solve the problem? Are you able to solve the problem for the innermost level of the dictionaries? Can you wrap up that logic in a function? Can you think of a way to iterate over an outer layer of the dictionary structure and apply that function's results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can turn your nested `dict` into a `DataFrame`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    (k0, k1, k2):v2
    for k0, v0 in perf.items()
    for k1, v1 in v0.items()
    for k2, v2 in v1.items()
}, orient='index')
```

Which gives:

```py
>>> df
              val_loss  val_accuracy
16 0.3 0.001       0.0           0.0
       0.010       0.0           0.0
       0.100       0.0           0.0
   0.5 0.001       0.0           0.0
       0.010       0.0           0.0
       0.100       0.0           0.0
   0.7 0.001       0.0           0.0
       0.010       0.0           0.0
       0.100       0.0           0.0
```

Then, as usual, you can find the index with highest accuracy:

```py
>>> df['val_accuracy'].idxmax()
(16, 0.3, 0.001)
```

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla Python (so not using df):

```
m = (0,0,0,0)

for x in p.items():
    for y in x[1].items():
        for z in y[1].items():
            a = float(z[1]['val_accuracy'])
            if a > m[-1]:
                m = (x[0],y[0],z[0],a)

print (m)
```

With this example:

```
p = {
16: 
    {
        0.3: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 3}},
        0.5: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 2}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}},
        0.7: {
            0.001: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 5}, 
            0.01: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0},
            0.1: 
                {'val_loss': 0.0, 'val_accuracy': 0.0}
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(16, 0.7, 0.001, 5.0)
```